The correct way of formulating change in enthalpy
I came across this question:

One mole of a non-ideal gas undergoes a change of state $(2.0 atm,
3.0L, 95K)$ to $(4.0 atm, 5.0L, 245K)$ with a change in internal energy = $30L atm$. Find the change in enthalpy (∆H) of the process in L atm.

For this I went with the general approach and wrote:
$$ H = U + PV \\
dH = dU + PdV + VdP $$
This way, my answer came out to be:
$$ dH = 30 + 2×(5-3) + 3×(4-2) = 40L atm. $$
However, the answer provided to the given question is $44L atm $ which comes by using:
$$ H_1 = U_1 + P_1V_1 \\
H_2 = U_2 + P_2V_2 \\
∆H = ∆U + (P_2V_2 - P_1V_1) $$
So, in what conditions should I go with the way prescribed? And what's wrong with my approach?

Your problem is with the mathematics.

Note that d(pV)=p.dV + V.dp, but Delta(pV) <> p.Delta V + V . Delta p  // Delta(pV) = p.Delta V + V . Delta p + Delta p . Delta V = p1 . Delta V + V2 . Delta p = p2 . Delta V + V1 . Delta p  // dH is infinitesimal, smaller in absolute value than any given positive number.

@Poutnik Thanks, that was indeed the problem. ∆P∆V was the missing term which I completely ignored and just went with the generalisation.

Note that
$$\text{d}(pV)=p.\text{d}V + V.\text{d}p, \tag{1}$$
but
\begin{align}
\Delta(pV) &= p_2V_2 - p_1V_1  \\
&\ne p \cdot \Delta V + V \cdot \Delta p\tag{2}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\Delta(pV) &= p \cdot \Delta V + V \cdot \Delta p + \Delta p \cdot \Delta V =\\
&= p_1 \cdot \Delta V + V_2 \cdot \Delta p =\\
&= p_2 \cdot \Delta V + V_1 \cdot \Delta p. \tag{3}
\end{align}
$\text{d}H$ is infinitesimal, smaller in absolute value than any given positive number.
Note that there is the algebraic convention in context of system states that the respective state variables with implicit (missing) indexes refer to the same, current system state. So, while there is inequality in (2), there can still be an equality in (3).

To solve the task:
\begin{align}
\Delta H &= \Delta U + \Delta (pV) =\\
&= \Delta U + p_1 \Delta V + V_2 \Delta p =\\
&= (\pu{30 L atm}) + (\pu{2 atm})(\pu{5 L} - \pu{3 L}) + (\pu{5 L})(\pu{4 atm} - \pu{2 atm}) =\\
&=(\pu{30 L atm}) + (\pu{4 L atm}) + (\pu{10 L atm}) =\\
&= \pu{44 L atm}
\end{align}
OR
\begin{align}
\Delta H &= \Delta U + \Delta (pV) =\\
&= \Delta U + p_2 \cdot V_2 - p_1 \cdot V_1 =\\
&= (\pu{30 L atm}) + (\pu{4 atm})(\pu{5 L}) - (\pu{3 L})(\pu{2 atm}) =\\
&=(\pu{30 L atm}) + (\pu{20 L atm}) - (\pu{6 L atm}) =\\
&= \pu{44 L atm}
\end{align}

Algebraically,$$P_2V_2-P_1V_1=\left(\frac{P_2+P_1}{2}\right)(V_2-V_1)+\left(\frac{V_2+V_1}{2}\right)(P_2-P_1)$$So, in your equation, you should be using the arithmetic average pressure and arithmetic average volume, not the initial pressure and volume.

That is correct, but it seems one of the most complicated ways of possible alternatives how to calculate it.  :-)

The OP needs to better understand the difference between $\Delta(PV)$ and d(PV).
